# IntelliJ IDEA group windows on secondary monitor

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

Is there a way to group windows on a secondary monitor ? Right now, i can move for example the Console or Debug window as a separate window on my second screen, but cannot seem to be able to group them.
On eclipse i was able to do something like this:

[image]

Does IntelliJ support something similar ? I can only seem to be able to group them on my main screen, but not once i undock them.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. You may follow the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55195

Comment: I suppose this translates to, no it is not possible :)

Comment: Yes, currently it's not possible.